# html+js: third time click the button,it will run the third function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I first click the button, it will appear an address selection, when my second, third click on the same button, it will be a second, third address selection, please help me how to use HTML and Javascript achieve this function, thank you!

Comment: What have you tried? :\ [Your reference](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Separately, please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [*How do I ask a good question*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: @CIKAI we cannot visualize what you are seeing in your screen right? :) So please share the code that you are working with. And explain the problem that you have with that code. That will help you to give better answers. :)

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy 
 
i have tried use button toggle, and for address selection, i use ajax reload a txt file for 3 times ... but it's not what i want, thank you! ( m not a native speaker, hope u could get what i mean and help me, thank you)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `.toggle()` in jQuery is obsolete in newer versions. It is better we set a flag and do it this way:

```js
$(function () {
  var inputCount = 0;
  $("input").click(function () {
    var functionsArray = [function () {
      alert(1);
    }, function () {
      alert(2);
    }, function () {
      alert(3);
    }];
    functionsArray[inputCount++]();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Click Me!" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
$('.addAddress').on('click', function() {
  $('.form').append('<input type="text" name="address" id="address"/>');
});
```

```css
.form input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form">
  <label for="address">Address</label>
</form>
<button class="addAddress">+</button>
```

Every time you click the `+ button` it will insert a new field into the form.